# Javascript split at multiple delimters while keeping delimiters

Tags: javascript, regex, match, delimiter

Is there a better way than what I have (through regex, for instance) to turn

```
"div#container.blue"
```

into this

```
["div", "#container", ".blue"];
```

Here's what I've have...

```
var arr = [];
function process(h1, h2) {
    var first = h1.split("#");
    arr.push(first[0]);
    var secondarr = first[1].split(".");
    secondarr[0] = "#" + secondarr[0];
    arr.push(secondarr[0]);
    for (i = 1; i< secondarr.length; i++) {
        arr.push(secondarr[i] = "." + secondarr[i]);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: why was this downvoted out of curiousity?

Comment: Probably because you've shown no effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: I added my solution, though I hate it.  If what I was missing was the attempt, can I please get the downvotes removed? =/

Comment: I can't remove the downvotes, but I'll upvote to compensate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not something like this?

```
'div#container.blue'.split(/(?=[#.])/);
```

Because it's simply looking for a place where the next character is either `#` or the literal `.`, this does not capture anything, which makes it a zero length match. Because it's zero-length match, nothing is removed.

Comment: I *knew* there was a better regex than mine.  +1

Comment: Is there a way to have the split carry the delimiter to the proceeding (rather than subsequent) word?

Answer (score 3):

As you've probably found, the issue is that `split` removes the item you're splitting on.  You can solve that with regex capturing groups (the parenthesis):

```
var result = 'div#container.blue'.split(/(#[^#|^.]*)|(\.[^#|^.]*)/);
```

Now we've got the issue that `result` contains a lot of falsy values you don't want.  A quick `filter` fixes that:

```
var result = 'div#container.blue'.split(/(#[^#|^.]*)|(\.[^#|^.]*)/).filter(function(x) {
  return !!x;
});
```

## Appendix A: What the heck is that regex

I'm assuming you're only concerned with `#` and `.` as characters.  That still gives us this monster: `/(#[^#|^.]*)|(\.[^#|^.]*)/`

This means we'll capture either a `#` or `.`, and then all the characters up until the next `#` or `.` (remembering that a period is significant in regex, so we need to escape it, unless we're inside the brackets).

Answer (score 1):

I've written an extensions of the Script type for you. It allows you to choose which delimiters to use, passing them in a string:

```
String.prototype.splitEx = function(delimiters) {
    var parts = [];
    var current = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (delimiters.indexOf(this[i]) < 0) current += this[i];
        else {
            parts.push(current);
            current = this[i];
        }
    }
    parts.push(current);
    return parts;
};

var text = 'div#container.blue';

console.log(text.splitEx('#.'));
```